# Augury doesn't work when angular's mode is dev

Tags: angular

I want to use Augury to debug my angular project, and I have used `isDevMode` to make sure that the mode is dev, but it doesn't work.

The Augury hint that

> This application is running in production mode and therefore cannot be inspected using Augury. If this is an Angular application, please rebuild your application in debug mode or remove the call to enableProdMode().

The project isn't created by angular cli, and Augury can work well with the project created by angular cli in my browser. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 11):

> Sometimes Augury doesn't load properly.

Try this:

After ng serve go to Developer console in chrome and select `Augury tab > Right click and Reload frame`, then it should work.

Comment: nope, didn't work, it won't show anything, then goes back to the same state.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved the problem by setting the debug flag to true in tsconfig.json, see in https://github.com/rangle/augury

`"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "debug": true
}`

Answer (score 0):

In `tscofig.json` add the below option

```
"angularCompilerOptions": { "debug": true }
```

in `main.ts` comment out enableProdMode();

```
// enableProdMode();
```

Reference : [Issue](https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1252) -> [Solution](https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1252#issuecomment-376447555)